# Could you please help me to find the values of the following equation using Mathematica

Tags: function-construction, summation

$$\zeta(m,n)=\frac{1}{2} \left[ 1+(-1)^n \right] \zeta(m) \zeta(n) +\frac{1}{2}  \left[ (-1)^n \binom{m+n}{n}-1 \right] \zeta(m+n) - (-1)^n \sum_{i=1}^{\frac{m+n}{2}} \left[ \binom{m+n-1-2i}{m-1} +\binom{m+n-1-2i}{n-1}  \right] \zeta(2i) \zeta(m+n-2i) $$

I need to get values for $\zeta(m,n)$  when $\zeta(m,n)$  are of $\color{red}{\text{different parity}}$. i.e. when $m+n=2k+1$

I want to study the different values of $\zeta(m,n)$ by using the above equation.

I tried to define $f(m,n ):=...$ and then, substitute values for $f(m,n)$. But it didn't work.

```
f[m_, n_] := 
    1/2 (1 + (-1)^n) Zeta[m] Zeta[n] + 
    1/2 ((-1)^n Binomial[m + n, n] - 1) Zeta[m + n] - 
    (-1)^n 
      Sum[
        ( Binomial[m + n - 1 - 2i, m - 1] + 
        Binomial[m + n - 1 - 2i, m - 1] ) Zeta[2i] Zeta[m + n - 2i] ,
           {i, 1, (m + n)/2}]
```

Comment: Please show the codes you've got so far.

Comment: You will greatly increase your chances of getting help here if you were to put more effort into your question. Make the question specific. "How can I write code for this." or something similar is never well-received. No one here wants to become your private tutor. If you have code that is not giving the results you want, show the code and describe exactly what you expected to get but didn't. If you don't know how to start coding what you want, describe your problem carefully in words giving the full set of inputs you would provide and what output you expect to get back.

Comment: @m_goldberg  I wrote the code I used. After that I substituted values for m, n. Sorry for not mentioning it

Comment: @kutaisi I mentioned the code above.

Comment: There are a number of syntax errors, the outer sum has no closing, and the inner sum lacks a , between the function and the summation parameters.

Comment: @Feyre thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of your ultimate goal, but the equation you present above does simplify quite a bit. Using your f[n,m], define:

```
g[n_, m_] = FullSimplify[f[m, n]]

1/2 (Zeta[m] Zeta[n] - Zeta[m + n] + (-1)^n 
      (-2 + Zeta[m] Zeta[n] + Binomial[m + n, n] Zeta[m + n]))
```

Now you can evaluate specific n and m:

```
g[3, 4]
1/2 (2 - 36 Zeta[7])
```

In particular, you always end up with a constant plus a term with Zeta[n+m]. You can get numerical values

```
g[3, 4]//N
-17.1503
```